# Test VerneMQ broker TLS with Mosquitto client

Tags: docker, ssl, docker-compose, mosquitto, mqtt-vernemq

### Background

- I setup and configured VerneMQ Broker. Broker is in docker container and I start it using *docker-compose.yml*. This is how my docker-compose file looks:

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  db:
    image: erlio/docker-vernemq
    container_name: vernemq1
    network_mode: docker_mysql_default
    restart: always
    environment:
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_ALLOW_ANONYMOUS: 'off'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_PLUGINS.vmq_diversity: 'on'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_PLUGINS.vmq_passwd: 'off'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_PLUGINS.vmq_acl: 'off'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY.auth_mysql.enabled: 'on'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY.mysql.host: 'docker_mysql'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY.mysql.port: '3306'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY.mysql.user: 'vernemq'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY.mysql.password: 'vernemq'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY.mysql.database: 'vernemq_db'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_VMQ_DIVERSITY.mysql.password_hash_method: 'md5'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__CAFILE: '/vernemq/etc/ssl/chain.pem'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__CERTFILE: '/vernemq/etc/ssl/cert.pem'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__KEYFILE: '/vernemq/etc/ssl/privkey.pem'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__DEFAULT: '0.0.0.0:8081'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__DEFAULT__USE_IDENTITY_AS_USERNAME: 'off'
      DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__DEFAULT__REQUIRE_CERTIFICATE: 'off'
    ports:
      # <Port exposed> : <Port running inside container>
      - '1883:1883'
      - '8081:8081'
    expose:
      # Opens port 1883 on the container
      - '1883'
      - '8081'
      # Where our data will be persisted
    volumes:
     - /var/lib/
     - /home/ubuntu/etc/ssl:/vernemq/etc/ssl
# Name our volume
volumes:
  my-db:
```

- I am using MySQL database for authentication
- I am trying to use TLS certificates, based on the provided documentation ( https://docs.vernemq.com/configuration/listeners#sample-ssl-config )
- This setup is fully functional when I'm not trying to accept SSL connections (this means, when I remove the following lines from *docker-compose.yml*):

```
DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__CAFILE: '/vernemq/etc/ssl/chain.pem'
DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__CERTFILE: '/vernemq/etc/ssl/cert.pem'
DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__KEYFILE: '/vernemq/etc/ssl/privkey.pem'
DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__DEFAULT: '0.0.0.0:8081'
DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__DEFAULT__USE_IDENTITY_AS_USERNAME: 'off'
DOCKER_VERNEMQ_LISTENER__SSL__DEFAULT__REQUIRE_CERTIFICATE: 'off'
```

- I tested/verified the TLS connection using *openssl* client:

  `openssl s_client -connect 172.18.0.4:8081 -key privkey.pem -cert cert.pem`

  I executed this from server localhost, 172.18.0.4 is the IP Address of vernemq docker container, 8081 is the expected SSL default port (listener) and key/cert are provided 
  and this is the outcome (I suppose it means the TLS listener works):
  [image: Text]

### Question

How can I test this using mosquitto client or any other mqtt client? 
I want to use TLS based connection when publishing and subscribing.

When I don't use TLS, this is how I execute *mosquitto_sub* (subscription client):

`mosquitto_sub -h <ip_address> -p 1883 -t topic -d -u user -P password -i client-id`

This is the response:
[VerneMQ Subscription](https://im5.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-5-36929e159694.png)

When I try to use TLS, I add the --key and --cert options to use private key and certificate:

`mosquitto_sub -h <ip_address> -p 1883 -t topic -d -u user -P password -i client-id --key privkey.pem --cert cert.pem`

I only get

`Client user sending CONNECT`

repeatedly. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

some things you need to do give correct permissions to your certificate directory you need to ensure the permission set to the user running verneMQ in my case its "**vernemq**" now next things is to setup the permissions to certificate folder

```
chown -R vernemq:vernemq /etc/letsencrypt/live
```

All the configurations files should be in .pem format

```
listener.ssl.cafile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtts.domain.com/chain.pem
listener.ssl.certfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtts.domain.com/cert.pem
listener.ssl.keyfile = /etc/letsencrypt/live/mqtts.domain.com/privkey.pem
```

Client must use Fullchain.pem to connect to Server if you do not have 
The domain certificate is issued by intermediate “Let’s Encrypt Authority X3”, this intermediate is cross-signed by “DST Root CA X3” (from IdenTrust). IdenTrust is widely trusted by most OSes and applications, we will “DST Root CA X3” as root CA.
if you are not on too old OS then you could use this from your local machine

```
cat /etc/ssl/certs/DST_Root_CA_X3.pem /etc/letsencrypt/live/$domain/chain.pem > ca.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

From the `mosquitto_sub` [man](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto_sub-1.html) page:

> **Encrypted Connections**
>
> mosquitto_sub supports TLS encrypted connections. It is strongly
>   recommended that you use an encrypted connection for anything more
>   than the most basic setup.
>
> To enable TLS connections when using x509 certificates, one of either
>   --cafile or --capath must be provided as an option.

---

> --capath
>
> Define the path to a directory containing PEM encoded CA certificates that are trusted. Used to enable SSL communication.
>
> For --capath to work correctly, the certificate files must have ".crt" as the file ending and you must run "openssl rehash " each time you add/remove a certificate.

To use the `mosquitto_sub` command you must supply either a file with the trusted CA certificate or a directory holding a collection of trusted CA certificates

Comment: I tried including --capath option with an absolute path to the _ssl_ folder.  
mosquitto_sub client outputs this response:  

OpenSSL Error: error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed  
Error: A TLS error occurred.  

VerneMQ log:  
[info] TLS server: In state certify received CLIENT ALERT: Fatal - Unknown CA

I am using the same certificate files for VerneMQ configuration.  
I tried both with fullchain and rootCA chain only.  
I am out of ideas what to try next.

Comment: try `--cafile` and point directly to the fullchain file (it needs to be in pem format)

Comment: To confirm: fullchain is in pem format.  I tried it and mosquitto response is: "Error: Problem setting TLS options: File not found." There is no VerneMQ output however. Do I need to add `--key` and `--cert` ?

Comment: File not found means you've got the path to the file wrong. And no you only need `--key` and  `--cert` if you are authenticating the client against with certs.

Comment: That's what bothers me. I'm 100% certain that is the file path.